# Traversing DOM nodes in CKEditor-4

Tags: dom, ckeditor

We have a  [bug at this CKEditor plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/texttransform#comment-127631), and a generic solution is [like to this](https://github.com/garyharan/jquery-replace-utilities/), applying a generic string-filter only to terminal text nodes of the DOM.

**QUESTION**: how (need code example) to traverse a *selection node* (`editor.getSelection()`) by CKEditor-4 tools, like [CKEDITOR.dom.range](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range)?

Comment: The answer of this question collaborated to [Aug 28, 2013 version of this plugin](https://github.com/onderceylan/ckeditor-texttransform-plugin/blob/master/plugin.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First step will be to get ranges from current selection. To do this just call:

```
var ranges = editor.getSelection().getRanges();
```

This gives you an array of ranges, because theoretically (and this theory is proved only by Firefox) one selection can contain many ranges. But in 99% of real world cases you can just handle the first one and ignore other. So you've got `range`.

Now, the easiest way to iterate over each node in this range is to use [`CKEDITOR.dom.walker`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.walker). Use it for example this way:

```
var walker = new CKEDITOR.dom.walker( range ),
    node;

while ( ( node = walker.next() ) ) {
    // Log values of every text node in range.
    console.log( node.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_TEXT && node.getText() );
}
```

However, there's a problem with text nodes at the range's boundaries. Consider following range:

```
<p>[foo<i>bar</i>bo]m</p>
```

This will log: `foo`, `bar`, and `bom`. Yes - entire `bom`, because it is a single node and **walker does not modify DOM** (there's a bug in documentation).

Therefore you should check every node you want to transform if it equals range's `startContainer` or `endContainer` and if yes - transform only that part of it which is inside range.

**Note**: I don't know walker's internals and I'm not sure whether you can modify DOM while iterating over it. I'd recommend first caching nodes and then making changes.

Comment: thanks a lot!  About the `walker` problem... Hum... Another way is to use DOM-2 standard Javascript methods: how to get the DOM of the editing (selected) text?  We can use XPath (`//text()`) or `document.querySelector`, etc. to iterate over all text nodes... And modify (after iterated all as you suggest) directally the `nodeValue` or `textContent` properties.

Comment: Another way to fix bug at the [cited plugin code](https://github.com/onderceylan/ckeditor-texttransform-plugin/blob/master/plugin.js) is by regular expression... How to get XHTML (like DOM `saveXML`)?  There are a `selection.getSelectedHTML()`  to replace  `selection.getSelectedText()` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your questions. And they seem to be unrelated to the main one.

Comment: The main subquestion here is about avoid `walker` (that not is a safe method!) and use  another more pritive method, perhaps a Javascript native DOM method... So the subquestion: how to get "real DOM" object from selection?  If I have a "pure DOM node" (not an extended class of CKEditor), I can traverse by traditional standard Javascript.

Comment: When I am trying to implement with `walk` as you suggested, I not see how to modify nodes: [CKEDITOR.dom.node](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.node) not show `getText()`, that works,  method neither an "putText", that I need.

Comment: Come on... I pointed you the API docs and you haven't found it? [CKEDITOR.dom.node](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.node) has two subclasses - [CKEDITOR.dom.text](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.text), [CKEDITOR.dom.element](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element). You can also get the native DOM nodes by accessing `node.$` and then use e.g. jQuery.

Comment: And I don't have ANY idea what do you mean by "avoid walker (that not is a safe method!)".

Comment: Thank you for showing the road! Now I undertanding the CKEditor's framework (!), I can use basic DOM as `node.$.textContent = "HELLO!";`. About `walker`, if I edit "`bo]m`" and editor's "to upper tool" changes to "`BOM`" (not "`BO]M`"!) it is a not safe tool... Well, that is what you say about `walker`: now I try and it works!