# How can I highlight elements that match a regex in CKeditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, syntax-highlighting, mustache

I want to be able to highlight (i.e. wrap in a span with a color, or some other way) all text that matches a regex in CKEditor. I'd probably add a button to do this, and a button to remove highlighting. My specific use case is to highlight all mustache variables in my HTML templates (make it really easy to see where there are mustache variables).

I've implemented a version where I replace a regex matching mustaches with a span and then the capture group. This appears to break on some templates when I test.

To remove the highlighting, I use editor.removeStyle, which doesn't seem to work in all cases.

Here is an example of what I've implemented:

```
editor.addCommand( 'highlightMustache', {
            exec: function( editor ) {
                editor.focus();
                editor.document.$.execCommand( 'SelectAll', false, null );
                var mustacheRegex = /{{\s?([^}]*)\s?}}/g;
                var data = editor.getData().replace(mustacheRegex, '<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">{{ $1 }}</span>');
                editor.setData( data );
            }
        });

        // command to unhighlight mustache parameters
        editor.addCommand( 'unhighlightMustache', {
            exec: function( editor ) {
                editor.focus();
                editor.document.$.execCommand( 'SelectAll', false, null );
                var style = new CKEDITOR.style( { element:'span', styles: { 'background-color': '#FFFF00' },type:CKEDITOR.STYLE_INLINE,alwaysRemoveElement:1 } );
                editor.removeStyle( style );
                editor.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            }
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I pretty much have the same problem. I need to be able to highlight something matching a regex during typing in CKeditor.

Comment: "This appears to break on some templates when I test." - How does it break? Also can you include a sample template in your question so that the problem can be reproduced? Similarly, "I use editor.removeStyle, which doesn't seem to work in all cases" - Can you give an example of where it doesn't work?

Comment: gsastry and @Polygnome what is your preferred solution now and do you have perhaps an example of it?  As I have a similar need to highlight beginning and end placeholder markers "{" and "}" respectfully.

Comment: @melutovich The feature was put on hold, and about half a year later we switched to Redactor. I no longer work on that part of the project, so I am not certain how it got solved in the end.

Answer (score 3):

The following approach worked for me in the past for a similar task:

1. Walk the DOM tree of the CKEditor document and combine all [text nodes](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.text) into a single string (let's call it `S`). Use [`CKEDITOR.dom.walker`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.walker) for that, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18474486) should help here. While walking the tree, build a collection of data structures (let's call it `C`) to store each text node object and the position of where its text starts within `S`.
2. Run your regex against `S`.
3. If the match is not found, stop.
4. Otherwise, using `C` collection, locate the *start* text node (let's call it `SN`), and offset within it, corresponding to the *start* character position of the match string inside `S`.
5. Using `C` collection, locate the *end* text node (let's call it `EN`), and offset within it, corresponding to the *end* character position of the match string inside `S`.
6. Create a [`CKEDITOR.dom.range`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range) object and position it using `SN` as the start and `EN` as the end (`startContainer`/`startOffset`/`endContainer`/`endOffset`).
7. Use [`CKEDITOR.dom.selection.selectRanges()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.selection) to select the range from the previous step.

Comment: This seems to be a good way to go about it. I'll check that out tomorrow ;)

Comment: @Polygnome, it works for fragmentation cases like `<span>bro</span><span>ken</span>` (`broken`), but you may need to account for other tags like `<td>bro</td><td>ken</td>`. Check the tag name when you walk the tree and add a space (or other separator) to `S` for all tags but `<span>`.

Comment: @Noseratio I have a similar need to highlight beginning and end placeholder markers "{" and "}" respectfully, is this still your preferred approach?  and do you have any example usages?

Comment: @melutovich, sorry but I haven't been working with CKEditor pretty much since then and I can't publish that code.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why don't you use a "reverse" Regex ofr the unhighlight command?

```
    editor.addCommand( 'highlightMustache', {
        exec: function( editor ) {
            editor.focus();
            editor.document.$.execCommand( 'SelectAll', false, null );
            var mustacheRegex = /{{\s?([^}]*)\s?}}/g;
            var data = editor.getData().replace(mustacheRegex, '<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">{{ $1 }}</span>');
            editor.setData( data );
        }
    });

    // command to unhighlight mustache parameters
    editor.addCommand( 'unhighlightMustache', {
        exec: function( editor ) {
            editor.focus();
            editor.document.$.execCommand( 'SelectAll', false, null );
            var mustacheRegex = /<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">{{\s?([^}]*)\s?}}<\/span>/g;
            var data = editor.getData().replace(mustacheRegex, '{{ $1 }}');
            editor.setData( data );
        }
    });
```

It should work fine!

Comment: This doesn't address fragmentation, like `<span>bro</span><span>ken</span>` for `broken`.

Comment: Yes, but for his own use-case it should work. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I don't, but maybe the OP and @Polygnome see that.